# Cant figure out how to make my range size variable

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CountHighSales()
    'This program asks the user for a threshold sales value. Then it finds the number of
    'sales in each region at least as large as the threshold. It also finds the total number
    'of sales at least as large as the threshold.
    Dim i, j As Integer         'i and j are counter variables
    Dim nHigh(6) As Integer     'nHigh is the number of sales over the threshold in each region
    Dim nHighTotal As Integer   'nHighTotal is the total number above the threshold
    Dim cutoff As Currency      'cutoff is the threshold value provided by the user
    Dim message As String       'message is text that we will report to the user
    Dim lastcolumn As Long





    'Ask the user for the threshold value and store it in the variable cutoff.
    cutoff = InputBox("What sales value do you want to check for?")
    'Count the number of sales values at least as large as cutoff.
    nHighTotal = 0              'Initialize the value of nHighTotal
    For j = 1 To 6              'Our range is 6 columns wide
        nHigh(j) = 0            'Initialize the value of nHigh(j)
        For i = 1 To 36         'Our range is 36 rows high
            If Range("SalesRange").Cells(i, j).Value >= cutoff _
                Then nHigh(j) = nHigh(j) + 1          'Increment nHigh if Sales >= cutoff
        Next i                  'Go to the next row
        'After all rows done, report the value of nHigh(j)
        'Note: the & operator joins/concatenates two strings.
        'Note: the Format function formats a numerical value using a specific formatting pattern we specify.
        message = "For region " & j & ", sales were above " & Format(cutoff, "$0,000") _
            & " on " & nHigh(j) & " of the 36 months."
        MsgBox (message)
        'Add the current regions total to nHighTotal
        nHighTotal = nHighTotal + nHigh(j)
    Next j                      'Go to the next column
    'Now report out the total number of sales exceeding the cutoff
    message = "The total number of sales, across all regions, above " & Format(cutoff, "$0,000") & " is " _
        & nHighTotal & "."
    MsgBox (message)
End Sub
```

Sorry I'm new to VBA. This is for a class I'm taking. I cant figure out how to get VBA to detect the number of rows and columns I have. I want it to be able to detect the rows and columns and then be able to ouput that data

Comment: When you say "Range" are you talking about a range of cells? What is `nHighTotal` here? What is `nhigh(j)`? Why are there `for` loops hanging out with nothing in them? There isn't enough info here to understand what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to determine the last row and last column used on a worksheet. This is what I generally use when I just need the number of each, as you do in your macro.

```
Dim lastCol as integer
lastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Dim lastRow as integer
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

Then you can rebuild your nhigh array

```
redim nhigh(1 to lastCol)
```

And loop through columns, then cells:

```
for j = 1 to lastcol
    nhigh(j) = 0
    for i = 1 to lastRow
       if ....
```